# nested json string column data to dataframe

Tags: python, json

I have json data with nested formate i tried normalizing with below code:

```
[{'account_number': 75cbhgfth0, 'annual_value_debit': 2800.0, 'annual_value_credit': 3100.0, 'accounting_sums_and_balances_month_values': [{'monthly_balance': 300.0, 'debit_credit_identifier': 'H', 'month': 12},{'monthly_balance': 300.0, 'debit_credit_identifier': 'H', 'month': 02},
{'monthly_balance': 300.0, 'debit_credit_identifier': 'H', 'month': 01}], 'balance': 300.0, 'balance_debit_credit_identifier': 'H', 'caption': 'BW-Abbruch GmbH', 'id': '75cxbffd'}]
```

> 

```
res = c.getresponse()
data = res.read() 
    data=json.loads(data.decode('utf-8'))
    df = pd.json_normalize(data, 'accounting_sums_and_balances_month_values',
 ['account_number'], record_prefix='ac_')
```

KeyError: "Key 'accounting_sums_and_balances_month_values' not found. If specifying a record_path, all elements of data should have the path."

Comment: Your code certainly works on the provided example. Check for cases in which the `accounting_sums_and_balances_month_values` key is missing.